# sentinel node in cpp list does not work as expected

Tags: c++

I am writing cpp-11 and want to create a list of list based on the data received. The data structure is std::list<char, std::list<char, int>>. The outer list stores a list of inner lists, and when several successive inner lists have the same label, then they should be grouped together, otherwise a new entry is created. Analogously, the inner list count the number of successive data entries that have the same label and stores the total count, otherwise create a new entry.

I use the following trick to avoid judging if the container is empty every time. By the beginning when a list is created, a sentinel node is inserted to the freshly created container. The sentinel node obtains a label that will never appear in the data received. So that every time a new data comes, I compare the data lable with the label of last entry, instead of inserting extra codes to judge if this is the first entry in the current list.

But it doesnot work as expected. It seems that the sentinel node is not inserted at all.

Here is the code.

```
#include <list>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using profileLoc = std::pair<char, size_t>;
using profileGrp = std::pair<char, std::list<profileLoc>>;

std::list<profileGrp> totalInfo;

void dump(bool isFinal=false){
  static int dumpCount = 0;
  if(isFinal) std::cout<<"Final ";
  std::cout<<"dump "<< ++dumpCount<<"\n";
  for(auto grp:totalInfo){
    if(grp.first==-1) continue;
    std::cout<<"grp label: "<<grp.first<<"\n";
    for(auto range: grp.second){
      if(std::get<0>(range)==0) continue;
      std::cout<<"\ttype label: "<<std::get<0>(range)<<" count: "<<std::get<1>(range)<<"\n";
    }
  }
}

int main(){

  profileGrp dummyGrp{-1,{{0,0}}};
  totalInfo.push_back(dummyGrp);
  

  using dataTy = std::tuple<int, char>;
  std::list<dataTy> sampleData{
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    //{'Y', 'c'},
    //{'Y', 'c'},
    //{'Y', 'b'},
    //{'Y', 'b'},
    //{'Y', 'b'},
  };
  
  for(auto data:sampleData){
    char grpNo;
    char typeNo;
    std::tie(grpNo, typeNo) = data;
    std::cout<<"receiving data "<<grpNo<<" "<<typeNo<<"\n";
    
    profileGrp& lastGrp = totalInfo.back();
    if(lastGrp.first != grpNo){
      std::list<profileLoc> dummyList{{0, 0}};
      totalInfo.emplace_back(grpNo, dummyList);
      lastGrp = totalInfo.back();
    }
    
    std::list<profileLoc>& locList = lastGrp.second;
    if(std::get<0>(locList.back())!=typeNo){
      locList.emplace_back(typeNo, 1);
    } else {
      size_t lastCount = std::get<1>(locList.back());
      locList.pop_back();
      locList.emplace_back(typeNo, lastCount+1);
    }
    
    //dump();
  }

  dump(true);
  return 0;
}
```

The result I get is:

```
receiving data X a
receiving data X a
receiving data X a
receiving data X b
receiving data X b
receiving data X b
Final dump 1
grp label: X
    type label: a count: 1
grp label: X
    type label: a count: 2
    type label: b count: 3
```

If you know how to fix the code please tell me. Thank you.

```
receiving data X a
receiving data X a
receiving data X a
receiving data X b
receiving data X b
receiving data X b
Final dump 1
grp label: X
    type label: a count: 3
    type label: b count: 3
```

Comment: Ehh, I am new to Cpp and don't get what you mean. Do you mean I should use a different container, or do not implement my own sentinel node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it work first and then try to make it works better.

Here is a revision with sentinel nodes removed. Try to add it back and compare with your code.

```
#include <list>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using profileLoc = std::pair<char, size_t>;
using profileGrp = std::pair<char, std::list<profileLoc>>;

class MyInfo{
public:
    MyInfo& AddEntry(char groupNo, char typeNo)
    {
        bool g_f = false;
        for(auto & g : totalInfo)
        {
            if(g.first == groupNo){
                bool l_f = false;
                for(auto& loc: g.second)
                {
                    if(loc.first == typeNo){
                        ++loc.second;
                        l_f = true;
                    }
                }
                if( !l_f )
                    g.second.emplace_back(typeNo, 1);
                g_f = true;
            }
        }
        if( !g_f )
            totalInfo.emplace_back(groupNo,std::list<profileLoc>{{typeNo, 1}} );

        return *this;
    }
    
#ifdef _DEBUG
    void Dump(bool isFinal = false)
    {
        static int dumpCount = 0;
        if(isFinal) std::cout<<"Final ";
        std::cout<<"dump "<< ++dumpCount <<"\n";
        for(const auto& grp:totalInfo){ // use reference if you don't want to make a copy
                  // here you don't need. the const modifier is a good practice
                  // to communicate to the compiler you have no 
                  // intention to modify it in the following for-loop scope
                   
        //if(grp.first==-1) continue;
            std::cout<<"grp label: "<<grp.first<<"\n";
            for(const auto& range: grp.second){
                if(std::get<0>(range)==0) continue;
                std::cout<<"\ttype label: "<<std::get<0>(range)<<" count: "<<std::get<1>(range)<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }
#else
    void Dump(bool){}
#endif
private:
    std::list<profileGrp> totalInfo;
};

int main(){
  using dataTy = std::tuple<int, char>;
  std::list<dataTy> sampleData{
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'a'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    {'X', 'b'},
    {'Y', 'c'},
    {'Y', 'c'},
    {'Y', 'b'},
    {'Y', 'b'},
    {'Y', 'b'},
  };
  
    MyInfo info;
  
    for(auto& data:sampleData){
        auto& [grp,type] = data;
        info.AddEntry(grp, type);
    }
    
    info.Dump(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Above implementation doesn't rely on data comes in sorted. If that's a given, `AddEntry()` can be revised to take advantage of that:

```
    MyInfo& AddEntry(char groupNo, char typeNo)
    {
        if( totalInfo.empty() || totalInfo.back().first != groupNo){
            totalInfo.emplace_back(groupNo, std::list<profileLoc>{{typeNo, 1}});
            return *this;
        }

        auto& _profLoc = totalInfo.back().second; // the std::list<profileLoc> we
                                               // are going to do more processing on
        if(_profLoc.empty() || _profLoc.back().first != typeNo )
            _profLoc.emplace_back(typeNo, 1);
        else
            ++_profLoc.back().second;
        return *this;
    }
```

Adding sentinels to save the `if list is empty` check should be piece of cake from here.

Comment: Grazie! This solves my problem. Meanwhile, I have also found a fix to the code in OP, though I don't figure out why it works: the problem does come from the sentinel node. You cannot reassign back() of a list to the same variable right after emplace_back(). I change the related code to  "if(totalInfo.back().first != grpNo){" and only after that if statement, "profileGrp& lastGrp = totalInfo.back();". The problem is solved though I don't understand. But anyway I found that your solution is cleaner and the empty judgement is not bad at all.

Comment: I was feeling that. I would use a `profile* pLastGrp;`.  Notice the subtle difference between pointer and reference. I always think reference as a pointer that when refer to, compiler take it as the object it points to. You can change a `profile* pLastGrp;` to point to another `profile` object. But for `profile& pLastGrp`, assignment always means modify the object pointed to by its underlying pointer, while the underlying pointer, once initialized, can only be  changed by hackish way. So if you want to change the underlying pointer of a reference, use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about `reference` and how it's related to `pointer`. Hope it will help AshZhao better understand `reference`.

```
int a{5}, b{500};

int& r = a;
```

What's `r`? It's a `reference` to an integer. What does that mean? The object `r` will take up a space as large as an `int *`, inside it, the address of `a` is stored.

now

```
r = b;
```

What will happen? The value of `b`(which is 500) is assigned to the interger that `r`'s underlying `pointer` points to, which is `a`. As much as you may wish the line could be interpreted as re-associated the reference `r` with `b` while leave `a` intact, the compiler wouldn't listen because the c++ language disallows that.

What if I really need to change the object it pointed to in my program after a few lines? Well, declare it as a `pointer`.

But here is a hack that you can use to change the underlying `pointer` to re-associate it with another object. It's a technique that can be useful in very rare cases, but it certainly serve to help understanding what `reference` actually is and it's relationship with `pointer`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntRef
{
    int& obj;
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a{10}, b{100};
    
    IntRef r{a};
    
    std::cout<<"Now `r.obj` is correctly referencing `a`, its value is "
            << r.obj <<std::endl;
            
    // I am going to make `r.obj` referencing `b`
    // you cannot take the actual address of `r.obj`
    // as `&r.obj` will always return the address of the object
    // it points to, not its own address.
    //
    // here we make use of the knownledge that it's the first member
    // variable of struct IntRef
    //
    *reinterpret_cast<int**>(&r) = &b;
    std::cout<<"I believe `r.obj` should be re-associated with `b` now, but let's verify it"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"`r`'s value is "<<r.obj<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Indeed! "Reference is an alias of a variable", thank you now I understand this textbook line better. Reassginment to a reference is not binding it to another object but modifying the very same object by initialization.